# Hats arrived? If yes then why i am not able to see them from mobile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have read that hats arrived but I am not able to see them on my Android phone.

Is this a bug or anything else? To clarify: I am not visiting Stack Exchange through an android app, I am using it through mobile internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I noticed this, too.

Hats are a script that loads after the rest of the site has loaded. Mobile, by nature, is a more stripped-down version of the site. As such, the extra sparkle of hats isn't going to be available on mobile. Add to that the fact that some mobile browsers aren't really good at javascript and you have a number of good reasons why hats don't work on mobile.

Comment: thanx @Aarthi for the un-delte and a good answer.